# I'm trying to solve SQL problem - https://sqlzoo.net/wiki/NSS_Tutorial, question no 6

Tags: sql

**Question**: show the percentage of students who `A_STRONGLY_AGREE` to question 22 for the subject '(8) Computer Science'; show the same figure for the subject '(H) Creative Arts and Design'.

Use the `ROUND` function to show the percentage without decimal places.

I can't understand how to use round function and percentage works together

My code:

```
SELECT 
    subject,
    ROUND(SUM(response * A_STRONGLY_AGREE) / 100, 0)
FROM 
    nss
WHERE 
    question = 'Q22'
    AND subject IN ('(8) Computer Science', '(H) Creative Arts and Design')
GROUP BY
    subject
```

Comment: No, your problem is not "how to use round function and percentage [...] together", but a semantic one. `SUM(response * A_STRONGLY_AGREE)` gives you the number of stundents  who A_STRONGLY_AGREE. Dividing this by 100 doesn't give you the percentage. You must divide by the total reponses instead. See Chaithra KC's answer.

Answer (score 2):

This query should work for the given problem.

```
SELECT subject, ROUND(SUM(A_STRONGLY_AGREE * response)/SUM(response))
FROM nss
WHERE question='Q22' 
AND subject in('(8) Computer Science','(H) Creative Arts and Design')
GROUP BY subject
```

1. `SUM(A_STRONGLY_AGREE * response)`:

This expression computes the total count of responses where students strongly agree with the specified question and subjects.

2. `SUM(response)`:

This part calculates the total number of responses received for the specified question and subjects including all the possible choices.

3. `SUM(A_STRONGLY_AGREE * response)/SUM(response)`:

With the values obtained in the previous steps, this expression computes the percentage of students.

Comment: Correct. You can remove `/ 100 * 100` and just keep `ROUND( SUM(A_STRONGLY_AGREE * response) / SUM(response) )`.

Comment: @Thorsten Kettner - I have updated my answer. Removing those unnecessary steps simplifies the query, and your suggestion makes it more concise and efficient. Thanks!